# redirect stdout to script, so it can be parsed and then sent to stdout

Tags: bash, redirect, stdout, pipe

I have a (java) program that prints a line of hex numbers to stdout every 5ish seconds, until the program is terminated by the user.

I would like to redirect that output to a bash script so I could convert each of those hex numbers independently to decimal, then print the parsed line to stdout.

I tried using myProgram | myScript but that did the piping before any lines were printed, then didn't keep listening to stdout. I then tried myProgram > myScript, and that just overwrote the script.

Ideas?

Edit: adding output from the runs, (sorry for the poor formatting, I couldn't get it all in the code highlighting) so the middle of the output is not highighted).

Here is the script

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $0
echo $#
echo $1
```

Here is how my program runs while it goes straight to stdout this would continue forever if I didn't terminate it.

```
mmmm@mmmm:~/mmmm/mmmm/mmmmm$ java net.tinyos.tools.Listen -comm 
serial@/dev/ttyUSB0:micaz
serial@/dev/ttyUSB0:57600: resynchronising   
00 FF FF 00 02 04 22 93 00 02 02 C9
00 FF FF 00 03 04 22 93 00 03 03 0E
00 FF FF 00 02 04 22 93 00 03 03 0E
00 FF FF 00 02 04 22 93 00 02 02 C9
^Z
[5]+  Stopped                 java net.tinyos.tools.Listen -comm          
serial@/dev/ttyUSB0:micaz
```

Here is where I try to pipe it to my script (which i have set to print the number of command line arguments and the first argument. It just freeze after this...

```
mmmm@mmmm:~/mmmm/mmmm/mmmmm$$ java net.tinyos.tools.Listen -comm serial@/dev/ttyUSB0:micaz | ./parser.sh
./parser.sh
0
serial@/dev/ttyUSB0:57600: resynchronising
```

Comment: Are you certain the output is going to standard out, and not standard error? Run `myProgram > /tmp/out 2> /tmp/err` and discover which output goes to which file -- `/tmp/out` for the standard output, `/tmp/err` for the standard error.

Comment: Sounds like you're not explicitly flushing stdout and it stops working automagically when it's not connected to a tty.

Comment: @sarnold I have confirmed using your example that the program sends to stdout

Comment: @cnicutar I am not sure what you mean? But I do not have the source for the program I am using so I cannot change it.

Comment: cnicutar's theory is a good one -- does the output in `/tmp/out` look identical (or very similar) to the output you would expect if you ran the program on the terminal without output redirection? If you run `nm -D /path/to/program | grep tty` do you see functions like `isatty` or `ttyname` used in the program? (Not _proof_, but perhaps useful information all the same.)

Comment: @sarnold This is going to sound ridiculous but I can't find the program I am calling... I call it like this: java net.tinyos.tools.Listen -comm serial@/dev/ttyUSB0:micaz

but I don't know where the net directory is...

Comment: Ahhh, a Java program. Java's standard libraries are going to be performing its own buffering, which is why the `stdbuf` answer suggested below (and the similar suggestion to use the `unbuffer` program) didn't work.

Comment: That doesn't sound promising...

Comment: I don't understand your original msg, i.e. "but that did the piping before any lines were printed". Can you edit your question to show what this looks like? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Hi, I added what it looks like both when I run it like normal and when I pipe it to my script, which is a very basic script at this time. (I'll add the script too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Diagnosis

When you use this script like this:

```
java javaprog | myScript
```

and `myScript` contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $0
echo $#
echo $1
```

Then the output from the script will be its name (`myScript`) from the `echo $0`, the number of arguments it was passed (0) from the `echo $#`, and the first argument (an empty line is echoed) from the `echo $1`.  The script then exits (successfully).  The issue is nothing to do with buffering; it is all to do with the script not reading anything from its standard input.  Even a trivial modification would be an improvement:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read data; do echo $data; done
```

That's a slower form of `cat`, except that it normalizes random sequences of spaces and tabs into single spaces, stripping leading and trailing spaces off the line.  It would at least demonstrate the script processing the output from the Java program.

---

#### Trying `awk`

To do what you're after, you should probably replace that with an `awk` program or something similar.  This is a first draft, but it stands some chance of working:

```
awk '{for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) { x = "0x" $i + 0; printf(" %d", x); printf "\n";}'
```

This says 'for each line (because there is no pattern before the open brace)', do 'for each of the fields 1..NF, convert the field into an explicit hex string with the `0x` prefix and adding 0, then print the value as a decimal number (trusting `awk` to convert a string such as '0xC9' to a number).

#### Using Perl

Unfortunately, a little testing shows that this does not work; the problem is getting a value other than 0 for `x`.  So, ... time to fall back on Perl in `awk`-emulation mode:

```
$ echo '00 C9 28 13 A0 FF 01' |
> perl -na -e 'for ($i = 0; $i < scalar(@F); $i++) { printf(" %d", hex $F[$i]); }
>       printf "\n";'
 0 201 40 19 160 255 1
$
```

That works - it's even fairly easy to understand.  The `-n` option means 'read each line of data and execute the commands in the script on each line (but do not print `$_` at the end)'.  The `-a` option combined with either `-n` (as here, or `-p` which is like `-n` except it prints `$_` automatically) means 'automatically split the input into the array `@F`.  The script then processes each element of `@F` in each line (rather verbosely), using the `hex` function to convert the string in `$F[$i]` to a number and then printing that number with `printf()`.  The verbosity can be reduced (this *is* Perl: There's More Than One Way To Do It, or TMTOWTDI - tim-toady) with:

```
$ echo '00 C9 28 13 A0 FF 01' |
> perl -na -e 'foreach my $i (@F) { printf(" %d", hex $i); } printf "\n";'
 0 201 40 19 160 255 1
$
```

Same result, less code.  There might be more abbreviated techniques; that's compact enough without being wholly illegible.

Comment: Ah success, Thanks Jonathan, and thanks to everyone who helped combat this issue with me.

Answer (score 1):

\1. check if your system has the unbuffer command installed

```
    which unbuffer
```

(typically systems that are using `bash` are Linux-based, and have `unbuffer` available)

\2. If yes,

```
    unbuffer myProgram | myScript
```

**edit**

As you have shown us your shell script as

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $0
echo $#
echo $1
```

Please recall that the values you are echoing, `$0, $#, $1` are positional parameters to bash **related to the command line arguments**. Typically options or filenames for processing.

To print the whole line, the # of fields on the line, and the value of the first line, awk is a perfect solution to this problem.

Try changing your script to

```
cat myScript.awk
#!/bin/awk -f
{ 
   print $0
   print $NF
   print $1
}

chmod 755 myScript.awk
```

Hmm.. Seeing `^Z` to stop input tells me you are using Windows or are you using bash under Cygwin?

I hope this helps.

Comment: @shelter I guess unbuffer is not installed on my system (Ubuntu 11.10), but I could install it with the expect-dev package, is that something I should be doing?

Comment: @Michael : See my comment at end of comments on your question +++ please not revisions to this comment +++ It's hard to say for sure. It probably will help, but there may be other issues with how your `myProgram` is handling its output. I'm not convinced this is a java output problem (per se), but is more about buffers not getting flushed at the right time. Not certain but I think unbuffer can help, even with java programs. Java gurus? Any experience to share? Good luck to all.

Comment: @shelter Thank you for fixing the code formatting in my question. I am on Ubuntu 11.10. The reason I made that script so simple was just because I wanted something (anything) to print each time a line got sent to the script. What I would be eventually be doing with the script is removing sets 1-4 and 6-9 of the hex sets, then converting the last two sets to a single decimal number. 

I tried your script though but I couldn't get it to run. I tried the following commands (after chmod)
`$ program | ./myScript.awk` got unexpected '.' and without the `./` got awk command not found. Thanks for help

Comment: @Michael : yes, I've 'fixed' the awk script. it was missing the `-f` on the first line. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a buffering issue. The GNU Coreutils come with a tool called `stdbuf`. If it is available on your system, try running:

```
stdbuf -o0 program | stdbuf -i0 script
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea but this didn't seem to change anything. It pipes the results of my myProgram before anything even happens. then never again.